# Why does my element align itself to its sibling? aka overflow: hidden on Parent breaks left: 50% on Children

Tags: html, css, overflow, margin

**Here's a brief explanation of my diagram (shown below):**
The yellow box is the parent.
The black and cyan boxes are children of the yellow box.
The excess cyan box is hidden by it's parent via `overflow: hidden`

Since `overflow: hidden` breaks `margin: auto`, I've attempted to center the black box to its parent (i.e. the yellow box) by using `left: 50%`. However, the black box aligns itself to the full width of the cyan box.

Could someone explain another way I can align the black box to the width of its parent? I would accept an answer that fixes `margin: auto` as well.

Here is my code:

```
.yellow-box {
    display:table-cell;
    height:498px;
    width:33.33333333%;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.cyan-box {
    display:block;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:654px;
    height:654px;
}

.black-box {
    width:144px;
    height:84px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}
```

[image: http://i.imgur.com/EDhFtEU.png]

Comment: Can you add your HTML as well?

Comment: Hey @Sidsec9 Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/js_test/8skkvode/embedded/result/

Comment: Hey @ManojKumar see my response to Sidsec9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a fantastic optical illusion you've accidentally created!

Really though, `left: 50%` is working just fine.  While it looks like `.black-box` is centering to `.cyan-box`, in reality `left: 50%` is moving the leftmost side of `.black-box`—not the center as you are expecting—to the center of `.yellow-box`.  Fixing this is easy with the addition of `transform: translate(-50%);` to `.black-box`.  This moves `.black-box` back 50% of its width, which truly centers it to its parent.

```css
.black-box {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.yellow-box {
  height: 498px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.cyan-box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 654px;
  height: 654px;
  background: cyan;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
```

The illusion breaks when the size of the page changes.  I've added a line down the center so you can see the middle of `.yellow-box`.

Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdaGVw?editors=110) comparing the difference.

```css
.yellow-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.cyan-box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 654px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
.black-box {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
}
.black-box-two {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box-two">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
```

So `.black-box` is not really aligning to it's sibling at all, it just looks that way.

If you want to be able to use `margin: 0 auto` then you need to use `position: relative` on `.black-box`.  Margin's have no affect on absolutely positioned elements.

```css
.yellow-box {
  height: 498px;
  width: 33.33333333%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cyan-box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 654px;
  height: 654px;
  background: cyan;
}
.black-box {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
```

If you use `position: relative` instead of `position: absolute`, margins once again take effect.  You can even still use `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` if you care to do so.

Here's an [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLGaZo?editors=110) contrasting the two working solutions with the code you provided (left is using `transform: translate(-50%)`, middle is the original code, and the right is using `margin: 0 auto`).

```css
.yellow-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 30%;
  position: relative;
  background: yellow;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.cyan-box {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 654px;
  height: 100px;
  background: cyan;
}
.black-box {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.black-box-two {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.black-box-three {
  width: 144px;
  height: 84px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  background: black;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
.half {
  width: 50%;
  border-right: 1px black solid;
  height: 100%;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box-two">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
<div class="yellow-box">
  <div class="black-box-three">
  </div>
  <div class="cyan-box">
  </div>
  <div class="half"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice solution David. I ended up using `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` to fix the same alignment issue I was having with `top: 50%`. How did you know `transform: translate(-50%)` would work? I figured it would move it right back to it's position, prior to the `left: 50%` declaration. Can you explain how `transform` works in this scenario or point me to an article that "demystifies" `transform`?

Comment: `transform: translate(-50%)` is based on the width of the element it's placed on, while `left: 50%` is based on the element that the positioned object is relative to.  So `left: 50%` moves the left edge to the middle and `transform: translate(-50%)` pulls it back half of it's own width; making it's center where the left edge once was.

Comment: Wow, you just gave me an **a-ha** moment. I haven't done any cross browser testing yet but I'll take your word for it. Thanks David.